# Is there a reason to use non-functional updates in setState?

Tags: reactjs

We can update states with functions to guarantee that the state being updated is the latest possible value like `setCount(c => c + 1)`, instead of using `setCount(count + 1)` to avoid confusion caused by multiple updates of a state, and the fact that these updates are batched.

It seems to me that on a codebase of at least some size, members can really benefit from always using functions to update. The only downside I can think of is that it is a little bit verbose to write functions instead of value updates.

Is there any realistic benefits to not using functions in a `setState`?

Comment: Functional form is only needed when the new state depends on the previous state. In other words, when the new state is calculated using the previous state. Otherwise, non-functional state update is fine.